# How can I use Ace-Editor in Angular?

Tags: angular, web-component, ace-editor

I'm developing a web component using Angular 12 and I am using ACE editor. I followed a tutorial (link below) step by step but ended up with weird results. I ended up having the editor in one thin column -in grey- and it's not connected to div.
(https://blog.shhdharmen.me/how-to-setup-ace-editor-in-angular)

Any clue why this happened?

seite.html

```
<div class="app-ace-editor"
     style="width: 500px;height: 250px;"
     #editor></div>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import * as ace from "ace-builds";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-studentfe',
  templateUrl: './studentfe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./studentfe.component.css'],
  encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})

export class StudentfeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  @ViewChild('editor') private editor: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     ace.config.set("fontSize", "14px");
     ace.config.set(
        'basePath',
        "https://ace.c9.io/build/src-noconflict/ace.js"
     );

     const aceEditor = ace.edit(this.editor.nativeElement);
     aceEditor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
     aceEditor.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");
     aceEditor.on("change", () => {
        console.log(aceEditor.getValue());
     });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of shadow dom encapsulation hiding global styles from ace

Add

```
 aceEditor.renderer.attachToShadowRoot()
```

to let editor know that it is in shadow dom element and needs to add extra styles to it.

Also basepath should not contain `ace.js`

```
ace.config.set('basePath', "https://ace.c9.io/build/src-noconflict/");
```